# Why transparent image from canva won't display on my website?

Tags: css, reactjs, image, gatsby, styled-components

I make a website for restaurant and I need to insert a transparent logo from canva, but 
after adding it won't show. It's weird, cause when I've tried with other images NOT from canva it was working. What is the problem?

Image is on png format, but I've tried in jpg and also nothing happened. I've added even images with background, but none is working.

Doesn't seem like it is the code problem, cause as I said pictures from other sources than canva normally display, but maybe.

A change file name solves nothing.

```
import styled from 'styled-components'

import LogoImage from '../images/Super Sogbu (3).png'

const Logo = styled.img `
position: absolute;
top: 5vh;
left: 5vh;
width: 10%;
height: 10vh;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background-image: url(${LogoImage}) no-repeat center center fixed;
color: black;
`;

export default Logo;
```

[image: How this problem looks like]

[image: File tree]

It's my first question here, so I don't know exactly how should I describe the problem, but I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: Could you try and rename the file so that there will be no spaces? For example: "Super_Sogbu_3.png"

Comment: @AnDrOiD didnt work :/

Comment: Please update your question with the change I suggested and a picture of the file tree.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like invalid css. It should be either :

```
background-image: url(${LogoImage});
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
background-attachment: fixed;
```

or

```
background: url(${LogoImage}) no-repeat center center fixed;
```

Comment: Nothing. Originally it was like that